# Cronjob to move files using keywords

Tags: linux, debian, cron

What will be the right cronjob command to move files from x folder to y folder based on a file name keywords? i'm using Debian 6.0 squeeze, and kinda new to cronjobs.

Comment: Cron jobs are no different than standard shell scripts for the most part. Write a shell script to do what you want and then run it as a corn job.

Comment: ok..i can do that, only i don't know the correct command for keywords...i need the script to move files that have the word "example" in them (just as an example :)

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you. I'd suggest that you go out and do some of your own research on she'll scripting. When you have done that, come back to us with specific questions you have on the process.

Comment: I didn't ask for you to do the work for me..i just didn't knew how to call a keyword in a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add into crontab something like:

```
0 1 * * *   mv  /x/*example*  /y
```

That pattern is a shell pattern to find more details about this run `man bash` and search for "Pattern Matching" in the "Pathname Expansion" section.

Comment: Thank you Mircea. thats what i needed to know to go forward, i just didn't knew how to call a keyword.